# How to: Swap options with jQuery while using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to find a way to swap option values between them while I am using jQuery UI. I made a simple fiddle which would swap options but it works only when I'm not using jQuery UI.

Working fiddle **without** jQuery UI loaded on Options: http://jsfiddle.net/mBMRp/

Working fiddle **with** jQuery UI loaded on Options: http://jsfiddle.net/FUUYq/

Thanks alot

Comment: can we have more info on the context? maybe there's a simpler way to accomplish the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to distroy selectMenu and rebind it check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBGar/)

```
 $('select').selectmenu();
$('.swap a').click(function() {
    var opt1 = $(this).parent().prev('.forms').find('option');
    var opt2 = $(this).parent().next('.forms').find('option');

    // Remove them from the dom.
    opt1.detach();
    opt2.detach();

    // And put them back.
    $(this).parent().prev('.forms').find('select').append(opt2);
    $(this).parent().next('.forms').find('select').append(opt1);
    $('select').selectmenu('destroy').selectmenu();
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir. I just understand the concept. I though jQuery moto was Do more, Write Less.